# Finding the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal block matrix of special form

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-analysis

Consider the following symmetric tridiagonal block matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}
    2I_{N \times N} & -I_{N \times N} & O & \dots  & O &O \\
    -I_{N \times N} & 2I_{N \times N} & -I_{N \times N} & \dots  & O&O \\
    O & -I_{N \times N} & 2I_{N \times N} & -I_{N \times N} \dots  & O&O \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &O \\
    \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &-I_{N \times N} \\
    O & O & O & \dots &-I_{N \times N}  & 2I_{N \times N}
\end{bmatrix}_{N^2 \times N^2}$$

Above matrix comes from an intermediate step of higher-dimensional 2nd order finite difference scheme of Poisson equation. I'm wondering what are the eigenvalues of above matrix. What I know currently is for following (SPD) tridiagonal matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 &0\\
    -1 & 2 & -1 & \dots  & 0&0 \\
    0 & -1 & 2 & -1& \dots  & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots&0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots&-1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots &-1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}_{N \times N}$$ It has eigenvalues $\lambda_j = 4sin^2(\frac{j \pi}{2(N+1)})$, $1 \leq j \leq N$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your $N^2 \times N^2$ matrix is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of your $N \times N$ tridiagonal matrix and $I_N$. In general, if you have a $m \times m$ matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ and a $n \times n$ matrix $B$ with eigenvalues $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$, then their Kronecker product $A \otimes B$ is a $mn \times mn$ matrix with eigenvalues $\alpha_i\beta_j : 1 \le i \le m, 1 \le j \le n$. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract_properties) for other properties)